# Can my ISP see request data being posted to a website when a DNS leak occurs

Tags: dns, ip, data-leakage, isp, surveillance

From what I understand, the ISP can see the host you're trying to connect to in the event of a DNS leak. But does that mean they can see the data being sent like the requests body? or even headers?

Or can they just see the IPs/Hosts you're requesting.

Does this also mean any website I visit has specific access to my home IP (not the DNS server)

Answer (score 1):

Are your browser requests using HTTP or HTTPS?

For the former, your ISP can see everything.

For HTTPS, your ISP cannot see the HTTP URL path, headers, request body or response.

I always change my DNS servers to not use the default ones provided by my ISP.

When possible, I use encrypted DNS providers such as Cloudflare.

You mention DNS leak. Modern and patched DNS servers do not leak information. They do log information, so an ISP can retrieve queries that you have made provided that level of logging is enabled.

> Does this also mean any website I visit has specific access to my home
> IP (not the DNS server)

Network traffic uses IP addresses. Any site you visit will know the public IP address of your network connection. Since ISPs normally maintain information about your assigned IP address, data collection can use information about your public IP address and date/time to correlate to a customer. That normally requires a subpoena, but is possible and does happen.

I am not sure what information you are trying to protect. You can assume that anything you do from a residential computer can be tracked or traced back to you. A typical computer has many apps, cookies, connections to cell phones, Google Maps, email, etc. that reveal large amounts of information. Just walking around town with your cell phone tells Google Maps everywhere you go.

Comment: I am speaking about a dns leak from a vpn. That would make a difference i suppose by hiding info from the isp

Comment: @NotAidan - Your question does not mention a VPN. Even with a VPN, you network must still make DNS queries. VPN's do not connect all the way to a DNS server. At some point the traffic leaves the VPN to talk to a public DNS server. Where the traffic leaves the VPN determines who can start seeing that traffic.